# how to play a video in c# windows application?

Tags: c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play video files using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127445/how-can-i-play-video-files-using-c)

please help me to play a video in c# windows application or using emgucv??

Comment: Winforms or WPF? The latter is very simple to do

Answer (score 0):

With WPF, you can create a MediaElement which has a source property that you can point to the URL of the video.  MediaElement exposes a number of methods for Play, Pause, Stop, Volume, etc.

If you need a Winforms solution see solairaja's answer.