# How can I play video files?

Tags: c#, video, file

I like to play video files, such as AVIs, through my C# program. Is it possible to play video files like that?

Comment: What video files? You need to be much more specific. What format? Which container type?

Comment: Supporting all of the video formats is tricky on windows, due to iffy support for all the codecs, and MPEG files can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use the Media Player control to play media files.

Example of playing audio from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(VS.85).aspx, you should be able to adapt it to video:

```
// [ C# ]
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;

private void PlayFile(String url)
{
    Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Player.PlayStateChange += 
        new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
    Player.MediaError += 
        new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaErrorEventHandler(Player_MediaError);
    Player.URL = url;
    Player.controls.play();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO  Insert a valid path in the line below.
    PlayFile(@"c:\myaudio.wma");
}

private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void Player_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot play media file.");
    this.Close();
}
```

There's a bit more information available on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564582(VS.85).aspx

Comment: you should add a windows media player controller to the form. Deatailed here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e628d9/playing-audio-and-video-files-using-C-Sharp/
And than use this code.

Answer (score 5):

You might consider using the Audio/Video controls in Managed DirectX as a quick solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497%28VS.85%29.aspx#dx_avp_playing_a_video_file

If you need more control over the video, or better integration with your application, you can use DirectShow.  There is a good C# interop library for accessing it ([DirectShowLib](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)).

One other plus of using DirectShow is that windows will handle loading the necessary codecs and rendering components necessary for a given media type.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use **Silverlight** to show video content and then plug the silverlight application into your web page.

What follows are some articles on creating a video player in silverlight:

http://www.85turns.com/2008/04/02/create-a-video-player-silverlight-2-part-1/

or

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-0-video-tutorials.aspx