# playing video file using form application in c# with DirectX and not with Windows media player

Tags: c#, video

i want to play video in c#. i searched related tutorial and i found [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/111181-adding-video-to-an-application/). i followed exactly the same but the video would not appear.

here is my code.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{    
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Video video;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // store the original size of the panel
            int width = panel1.Width;
            int height = panel1.Height;

            // load the selected video file
            //video = new Video("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Desktop\\Example.avi");
            video = new Video(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            // set the panel as the video object’s owner
            video.Owner = panel1;

            // stop the video
            video.Stop();

            // resize the video to the size original size of the panel
            panel1.Size = new Size(width, height);

            try
            {
                video.Audio.Volume = 100;
            }
            catch { }
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (video.State != StateFlags.Running)
        {
            video.Play();
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (video.State == StateFlags.Running)
        {
            video.Pause();
        }


    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (video.State != StateFlags.Stopped)
        {
            video.Stop();
        }


    }
    }
}
```

i even tried to put a path of the video like this:

```
video = new Video("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Desktop\\Example.avi");
```

but both of it will show the error like picture below.
[image]

my question is, how i want to enable to view and play the video by using windows form application in c#?

p/s: i want to use Directx only and do not want to play the video in windows media player.

Comment: Hope this help you.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127445/how-can-i-play-video-files-using-c

Comment: Did you refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018924/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322?

Comment: i want the video to play by using DirectX and i dont want it to play in Windows Media Player. is there a way to solve this exception?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20441933/2263683) can help