# Play video without using media player [Winform]

Tags: c#, winforms, video, audiovideoplayback

I want to play a video like that guy did  [[link]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_Pw04iHf7g&feature=player_detailpage#t=552s).

I'm working on C# Windows Form Application (not NXA).
But I don't know how.
I tried using `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` but no luck.

This is what I tried so far :

```
OpenFileDialog rihanna = new OpenFileDialog();
if(rihanna.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    video = new Video(rihanna.FileName);
    video.Owner = panel1;    
    video.Stop();    
}
```

Now what can i do? I tried using video class but as I said it just did not work.
I'm able to compile but when I'm running the program, I don't see the form window.

Answer (score 6):

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;

namespace Play_Video
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Video vdo;

    public string mode="play";
    public string PlayingPosition, Duration;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VolumeTrackBar.Value = 4;
    }



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PlayingPosition = CalculateTime(vdo.CurrentPosition);
        txtStatus.Text = PlayingPosition + "/" + Duration;

        if (vdo.CurrentPosition >= vdo.Duration)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            Duration = CalculateTime(vdo.Duration);
            PlayingPosition = "0:00:00";
            txtStatus.Text = PlayingPosition + "/" + Duration;
            vdo.Stop();
            btnPlay.BackgroundImage = Play_Video.Properties.Resources.btnplay;
            vdoTrackBar.Value = 0;
        }
        else
            vdoTrackBar.Value += 1;

    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (vdo != null)
        {
            vdo.Stop();
            timer1.Stop();
            btnPlay.BackgroundImage = Play_Video.Properties.Resources.btnplay;
            vdoTrackBar.Value = 0;

        }
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select video file..";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".avi";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Media Files|*.mpg;*.avi;*.wma;*.mov;*.wav;*.mp2;*.mp3|All Files|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            Form1.ActiveForm.Text = openFileDialog.FileName + " - Anand Media Player";
            vdo = new Video(openFileDialog.FileName);

            vdo.Owner = panel1;
            panel1.Width = 700;
            panel1.Height = 390;
            Duration = CalculateTime(vdo.Duration);
            PlayingPosition = "0:00:00";
            txtStatus.Text = PlayingPosition + "/" + Duration;

            vdoTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
            vdoTrackBar.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(vdo.Duration);
        }
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (vdo != null)
        {
            if (vdo.Playing)
            {
                vdo.Pause();
                timer1.Stop();
                btnPlay.BackgroundImage = Play_Video.Properties.Resources.btnplay;
            }
            else
            {
                vdo.Play();
                timer1.Start();

                btnPlay.BackgroundImage = Play_Video.Properties.Resources.pause;
            }
        }

    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vdo.Stop();
        timer1.Stop();
        btnPlay.BackgroundImage = Play_Video.Properties.Resources.btnplay;
        vdoTrackBar.Value = 0;
    }

    public string CalculateTime(double Time)
    {
        string mm, ss, CalculatedTime;
        int h, m, s, T;

        Time = Math.Round(Time);
        T = Convert.ToInt32(Time);

        h = (T / 3600);
        T = T % 3600;
        m = (T / 60);
        s = T % 60;

        if (m < 10)
            mm = string.Format("0{0}", m);
        else
            mm = m.ToString();
        if (s < 10)
            ss = string.Format("0{0}", s);
        else
            ss = s.ToString();

        CalculatedTime = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", h, mm, ss);

        return CalculatedTime;
    }

    private void VolumeTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (vdo != null)
        {
            vdo.Audio.Volume = CalculateVolume();
        }
    }
    public int CalculateVolume()
    {
      switch (VolumeTrackBar.Value)
        {
            case 1:
                return -1500;
            case 2:
                return -1000;
            case 3:
                return -700;
            case 4:
                return -600;
            case 5:
                return -500;
            case 6:
                return -400;
            case 7:
                return -300;
            case 8:
                return -200;
            case 9:
                return -100;
            case 10:
                return 0;
            default:
                return -10000;
        }
    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Duration = CalculateTime(vdo.Duration);
        PlayingPosition = "0:00:00";
        txtStatus.Text = PlayingPosition + "/" + Duration;
    }

    private void vdoTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (vdo != null)
        {
            vdo.CurrentPosition = vdoTrackBar.Value;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MaximizeBox = false;
    }

    private void exitToolItem_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where to get `Microsoft.DirectX`?

Comment: Microsoft.DirectX is an abondend along with XNA. Last Visual studio that support it is 2010 if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 3):

Okey Namespace is clear:

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
```

Some Global Variables in Form:

```
Video vdo;
public string mode="play";
public string PlayingPosition, Duration;
```

And now in your Button or what else to open:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select video file..";
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".avi";
openFileDialog.Filter = "Media Files|*.mpg;*.avi;*.wma;*.mov;*.wav;*.mp2;*.mp3|All Files|*.*";
vdo = new Video(openFileDialog.FileName);

vdo.Owner = panel1;
panel1.Width = 700;
panel1.Height = 390;
Duration = CalculateTime(vdo.Duration);
PlayingPosition = "0:00:00";
txtStatus.Text = PlayingPosition + "/" + Duration;

vdoTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
vdoTrackBar.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(vdo.Duration);
```

And in some other Button Code to Start/Pause:

```
if (vdo.Playing)
{
   vdo.Pause();
   btnPlay.Text= "Play";
}
else
{
   vdo.Play();
   btnPlay.Text= "Pause";
}
```

---

BTW:
**Don't name** variables/members or **something** else in your Code **after Girls**...

If your aren't sure how to name it, there are some [Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) here.

> The goal is to provide a consistent set of naming
>   conventions that results in names that **make immediate sense** to
>   developers.

Comment: She did not used variables names after girls, she was playing a video and probably had a constant file with the path of the video, the constant was named "rihanna.FileName" so i guess this is saying that this is Rihana´s Video (if you don´t know, Rihana is a singer so this is probably e video clip or something.)

Comment: @GabrielVonlantenC.Lopes that would be the name of a `string` then, not the name of an `OpenFileDialog` instance

Comment: When I try to run I get an exception:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback, Version=1.0.2902.0

Comment: "BTW: Don't name variables/members or something else in your Code after Girls..." @Smartis do you think the compiler will get offended? :)

Answer (score 2):

For AudioVideoPlayback to work, you'll need to add the AudioVideoPlayback reference, with Reference > Add Reference > Browse > C: > Windows > Microsoft.Net > DirectX for managed code > 1.0.2902.0 > Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll

Comment: When I try to run I get an exception:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback, Version=1.0.2902.0