# play a video with visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play video files using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127445/how-can-i-play-video-files-using-c)

I need to make a form to play a video with visual C# and the video will play in the form

it should have a "play" button and "stop" button

what is the right code for this form??

and thanks a lot for your concern..

Comment: Please make a minimal effort to search for answers before you ask.  Type "c# play video" in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DirectX to do it.
First you'll need to download the DirectX SDK, which you can find here http://msdn.microsoft.com/directx/sdk/
In your c# project, add a reference to Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
You can then use the following code to play a movie

```
//create the video
Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video video = new Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video(fileName);
//set the System.Windows.Forms.Control to play it in (e.g a panel)
video.Owner = panel1;
//Play the video (put this in a buttons click event)
video.Play();
//Pause the video (put this in a buttons click event)
video.Pause();
//Stop the video (put this in a buttons click event)
video.Stop();
```

When you are done, don't forget to call Dispose() on the video object.

Comment: How can you do this from an Embedded Resource as a stream ?